# QgsLayerMetadata.combine(other) doesn't seem to work as intended in pyqgis application

Tags: pyqgis, metadata

Using Pyqgis, I am attempting to create rasters from some calculations then applying a stored metadata.qmd file from an elevation layer to those rasters as a default. I am able to successfully create the rasters and apply some of the user defined metadata elements, e.g.

```py
m = layer.metadata()

omd = other_layer.metadata()

m.setFees($1M)

m.setCrs(QgsCoordinatedReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(4326))

m.combine(omd)

layer.setMetadata()
```

Documentation states I should be able to take metadata from another object (QgsMapLayer in my case) and do m.combine(other_layer_metadata). Applying this approach has no effect on the targeted raster. Any advice or suggestions?